# Bootstrap - How to format label color within a form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to bootstrap, I am using bootstrap 3. As you can see in the below image, I want the label(?) "Name", "Email Address", "Phone Number" and "Message" to be white and not dark grey.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="success" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <hr class="star-light">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
                <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-default"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have a custom css file but do not know the css code to make the "Name", "Email Address", "Phone Number" and "Message" to be white and not grey.

```
.floating-label-form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.floating-label-form-group input,
.floating-label-form-group textarea {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  resize: none;
}
.floating-label-form-group label {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  line-height: 1.764705882em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
  transition: top 0.3s ease,opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.floating-label-form-group:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
  color: #18BC9C;
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Please add css code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not a Label but placeholder of input

So, that you need to style placeholder by css:

```
.floating-label-form-group textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.floating-label-form-group  input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }
.floating-label-form-group textarea:-moz-placeholder ,
.floating-label-form-group  input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #fff; }
.floating-label-form-group  textarea::-moz-placeholder,
.floating-label-form-group  input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #fff; }
.floating-label-form-group  textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,
.floating-label-form-group  input:-ms-input-placeholder {   color: #fff; }
```

Working Fiddel :https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27294/

Answer (score 0):

you can apply white color to label as below

```
form label{
  color: #fff;
}
```

see working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27279/) here

Comment: Seems to be clashing with the other CSS code and not working. Not sure why though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the colour of the placeholder text as that is what is being displayed.

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27309/

The CSS

```
 /*This changes your placeholder text to white*/
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: white; }
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }
```

If you did want a label you could add a `h3` tag inside the `.control-group` `div` and then target it like this

```
/*This changes the h3 tag above your placeholder text*/
.control-group h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

This gives you the result as shown in the fiddle above which uses your code.